# Closing resource coming as return from method

Tags: java, inputstream, autocloseable

I have a helper class with a static method that returns a stream:

```
public static InputStream getDocument(File file) throws IOException {
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
    return zipFile.getInputStream(zipFile.getEntry("entry"));
}
```

Another class accesses that method and uses that returned stream:

```
InputStream is = MyClass.getDocument(new File(str));
```

My code works.

---

However, [according to the Java Documentation,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) I should close my resource:

> A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

But, when I implement `try-with-resources`:

```
public static InputStream getDocument(File file) throws IOException {
    try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);) {
        return zipFile.getInputStream(zipFile.getEntry("entry"));
    }
}
```

or `try-finally`:

```
public static InputStream getDocument(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(docx);
        is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipFile.getEntry("entry"));
        return is;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

I get an exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

---

How to make sure, that resource will be closed, **after** its use?

Comment: the caller is responsible to close the resource

Comment: @tkruse How is that a duplicate of this question?

Comment: try with resources adds an implicit finally block, in which it closes the resource. Therefore in both cases, the resource (stream) is closed at the end of the code block. So we have no other options but to differ closing the resource at the method calling site.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991577/closing-java-inputstreams, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980241/why-closing-an-input-stream-closes-the-associated-file-descriptor-as-well-even, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274432/does-a-zipentry-persist-after-a-zipfile-is-closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the caller is responsible to close/release the resources.
You can use the *try-with-resource* or the *try-finally* construct outside the method as follows:

```
try (InputStream is = getDocument(aFile) {
    //… do your stuff
}
```

If I can give you an advice, write it in the method documentation:

```
/**
  * The caller is required to close the returned {@link InputStream}
  */
public static InputStream getDocument(File file) throws IOException
```

Comment: I noticed, that SonarQube qualified it as a bug, that my resource has not been closed directly in the method. That's why I was wondering...

Comment: It seems to be a false positive in SonarQube. I saw a similar issue some days ago

Comment: If you guys are talking about this, https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2060 it should be fixed by now

Answer (score 0):

try-with-resources does implicitly the same as your second approach with `finally`. There is no way to close the zipFile but return an inputStream based on this zipFile.

Generally it would be better to avoid this helper method and use a single try-with-resourrces with multiple resources:

```
try (
   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
   inputStream inputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(zipFile.getEntry("entry"));
) {
    // Do stuff
} // Both zipFile and inputStream closed here implicitly
```

If you need to create such a method, you can however make sure that when the stream is closed, the zipFile object also gets closed.

From a related question  [Does a ZipEntry persist after a ZipFile is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274432/does-a-zipentry-persist-after-a-zipfile-is-closed)

```
zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
InputStream zipInputStream = ...
return new InputStream() {
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return zipInputStream.read();
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // Better add try/catch around each close()
        zipInputStream.close();
        zipFile.close();
    }
}
```

That way, when the calling method closes the stream it receives, the zip file would also be closed.

Comment: the only thing common between these two questions is the word "Stream"

Comment: No there is a subtle difference, This question is about the returned stream being closed prematurely but in the question you mentioned. It is about making sure to close the resources which are used in creating a Stream (of Strings).

Comment: I care cause you voted to close the question and also provided an answer that does not fully address the question.

Comment: I have completely changed my answer and turned it into community wiki. Feel free to use it, though accepted answer might get more views.